# How to generate dynamic response from the stubs without re-generating it again?

Tags: stub, spring-cloud-contract

I know Groovy DSL is able to generate a random value. 
I have used stub runner server so that I can hit the stubs from the server and get response. however when I refresh the browser I get the same response again. The Groovy DSL is just generating a static stub, and is always returning  the same response as I requested.

How can I get a random response without re-generate the stubs in this case?

Also a similar question was asked by someone a year ago, it was written in the answer that it is not possible. Is it still not possible or there is a way now to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to create your own WireMock extension. Check this section of the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/advanced.html#customization-wiremock

> 95.5.6 Registering Your Own WireMock Extension WireMock lets you register custom extensions. By default, Spring Cloud Contract
> registers the transformer, which lets you reference a request from a
> response. If you want to provide your own extensions, you can register
> an implementation of the
> org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.dsl.wiremock.WireMockExtensions
> interface. Since we use the spring.factories extension approach, you
> can create an entry in META-INF/spring.factories file similar to the
> following:

```
org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.dsl.wiremock.WireMockExtensions=\
org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.provider.wiremock.TestWireMockExtensions
org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.ContractConverter=\
org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.TestCustomYamlContractConverter
```

> The following is an example of a custom extension:

`TestWireMockExtensions.groovy.`

```
package org.springframework.cloud.contracthttps://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/advanced.html#customization-wiremock.verifier.dsl.wiremock

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.Extension

/**  * Extension that registers the default transformer and the custom one  */ class TestWireMockExtensions implements WireMockExtensions {     @Override   List<Extension> extensions() {      return [
                new DefaultResponseTransformer(),
                new CustomExtension()       ]   } }

class CustomExtension implements Extension {

    @Override   String getName() {      return "foo-transformer"    } }
```

You would have to create an extension that modifies the response and generates a piece of it. That extension needs to be available both on the consumer and the producer sides.